# 403 Forbidden when trying to download an image on Android

Tags: android, http, http-status-code-403, android-volley, okhttp

I'm having issues with downloading images on Android from one particular server. 
I have tried UniversalImageLoader, Picasso and most recently also Volley (also with custom HurlStack running on OkHttp). I'm getting 403 response code. In browsers (Chrome, Firefox, even on Android), or via wget and curl it downloads ok - no problems. 
I have tried to alter the user agent of my connection, but there is always the 403 in response.
This is my current code

```
MyImageRequest imgRequest = new MyImageRequest(mImgUrl, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            image.setImageBitmap(response);
        }
    }, 0, 0, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.networkResponse.statusCode + "");
        }
    });
    imgRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        5000,
        10,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    try {
        imgRequest.getHeaders().put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11");
    } catch (AuthFailureError authFailureError) {
        authFailureError.printStackTrace();
    }
    ProjectApp.getRequestQueue().add(imgRequest);
```

and this is example link http://www.airbank.cz/cs/kde-nas-najdete/nase-pobocky/praha/praha-nc-eden/galerie/Contents/0/ECEA50421E53119936698E51648FE8CE/original.jpg
Other images downloads without problems..Do you know where could be the issue? Or what can I do to better debug this issue..? Thank you..

Comment: Since this error is returned by the server, you need to examine the server logs.

Comment: That would be great, but I'm afraid that's rather problematic for me, since I don't have direct access there..:)

Comment: Does it work with mobile web browser? Have you tried removing User-Agent headers from your request?

Comment: Yes..it works in mobile browsers and yes I've tried it without headers.. I've had initially the most lighweight version with networkimageview and its setImageUrl() method.. Since it didn't work I tried several other combinations.

Comment: Interesting error, I'll check tomorrow morning when I get to work if I get 403 also, will report the result later

Comment: I've just downloaded your image using Volley with NetworkImageView and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Does it work for you repeatedly and without cache? Actually I managed to download the image I've posted the link to, but others subsequent requests failed to load..And since those others failed, also the first one is faling now as well again. Urgh:O

Comment: I'm using volley with no cache and got 403 as well with my client application, however it's hard to get the reason why since we cannot get the server logs :(

Comment: @simekadam you're right, trying repeatedly without cache I do get a 403. The answer must be on the server side.